# How to properly capture the return value of a unix command?

Tags: perl, shell, return-value

I'm having trouble getting the return value of a unix command into a perl variable.

Unix command:

```
#nc -z 8.8.8.8 441; echo $?
1
```

Perl command:

```
#perl -e 'my $pstate=`nc -z 8.8.8.8 441; echo $?`; print $pstate;'
0
```

So the perl command seems to get a return value of "no error"? How can  I properly capture the return value of the *nix command?

Another instance:

```
#perl -e 'my $pstate=`ping -v 8.8.8.8 -c 1`; print $pstate;'
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

This returns the proper value. So what am I doing wrong in the first instance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Variables are interpolated inside backticks, so the `$?` in

```
my $pstate=`nc -z 8.8.8.8 441; echo $?`
```

refers to Perl's `$?`, not the shell's `$?`. And what the shell sees is something like

```
nc -z 8.8.8.8 441 ; echo 0
```

To fix this, you can escape the shell command

```
my $pstate=`nc -z 8.8.8.8 441; echo \$?`;
```

or use the `qx` operator with the single quote as a separator (this is the one exception to the "interpolation inside the `qx` operator" rule)

```
my $pstate=qx'nc -z 8.8.8.8 441; echo $?';
```

or use `readpipe` with a non-interpolated quote construction

```
my $pstate= readpipe( 'nc -z 8.8.8.8 441; echo $?' );
my $pstate= readpipe( q{nc -z 8.8.8.8 441; echo $?} );
```

Comment: Ah. I assumed that the single quotes would escape the `?`

Comment: They are backticks, which are different from single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/IPC-Run3-0.046/lib/IPC/Run3.pm) which "allows you to run a subprocess and redirect stdin, stdout, and/or stderr to files and perl data structures".

Similar to system, you can inspect $? afterwards in various ways including shifting by 8 to get the actual exit code like this:

```
if ($? == -1) {
print "failed to execute: $!\n";
}
elsif ($? & 127) {
printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
($? & 127), ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
}
else {
printf "child exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;
}
```

This block is taken from the system documentation here http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html which also mentions what [devnull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235132/devnull) said.  Anytime I care about more than the one thing that qx or system does I switch to IPC::Run3 because it makes it easy to get everything.